# Delete Element from Map immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

How can I remove one element with an immutablejs map. Here is my code.

```
const initialState = Map({
            job: [
                {text: 'a'},
                {text: 'b'}
            ]
        });

const newState = initialState.delete({job: [text: 'a']});
```

But that is not working. Tried different ways but couldn't make it work.

Comment: `({job: {text: 'a'}}) === ({job: {text: 'a'}}) // false`. You have to use reference to **that** object that you want to remove, not different object with the same structure and values.

Comment: @Ginden I thought this would be done automatically by immutable.js, no?

Comment: As you see, it isn't.

Comment: Made you a fiddle with some options - first using the key to remove the entire first value, second acting on the value (which breaks the immutability)
http://jsfiddle.net/16xzhnaL/1/

Comment: Thinking maybe the confusion here is that you think you're trying to remove one element from a two-element map, but in this example you actually have a single element map with a key of job and a value of an array containing two elements.

Comment: @Mic thanks for the fiddle. Yes. I was trying to remove based on the value and not the key. I guess it's not possible. I will try with a filter in that case. Thanks

Comment: @LeonardoAlves yeah, I actually revised the fiddle with an ES5 filter inside a Map constructor. Maybe closer to what you're after. http://jsfiddle.net/16xzhnaL/2/
Ultimately even if it was able to match on value, the value would be the whole array, right?

Comment: @Mic Yes you are right. Not sure what I was thinking. The filter works as needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [deleteIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/deleteIn) and a property map to delete deep properties of an immputable map.

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
            job: [
                {text: 'a'},
                {text: 'b'}
            ]
        })

console.log(initialState.toJS());

const newState = initialState.deleteIn(["job","0"])

console.log(initialState.toJS());
console.log(newState.toJS());
```

Also you can use Lodash [_.toPath](https://lodash.com/docs#toPath) method to convert string paths in dot notations to property path arrays

```
const path = _.toPath("job[0].text") //["job", "0", "text"]
const value = initialState.getIn(path) //a
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example states you have a Map but it looks like your map contains mutable data values. Creating a Map like this..

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'

const initialState = Immutable.Map({
  job: [
    {text: 'a'},
    {text: 'b'}
  ]
})
```

will result in a data structure that looks like this...

```
Map {
  job: [
    {text: 'a'},
    {text: 'b'}
  ]
})
```

where `job` is an Array and the array entities are Objects.

If this is in fact the data structure you desire, you might try using [mudash](https://github.com/brianneisler/mudash) which is capable of handling mixed data types.

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import _ from 'mudash'
const initialState = Immutable.Map({
  job: [
    {text: 'a'},
    {text: 'b'}
  ]
})
const newState = _.delete(initialState, 'job[0]')   // Map { job: [{text: 'b'}] }
```